# Where can I find the path to Apple Watch extension for dlopen()?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'm trying to add an Apple Watch extension to my existing app which currently supports iOS v6.0. I don't want to give that up just yet, so I'm trying to implement dynamic loading of the extension as described here: [Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3)

It says I need to use dlopen(), but how do I determine the path of my new extension?

I also understand that I need to unlink the extension from my project target so that it doesn't automatically load. I see the name in General / Embedded Binaries is "ABC WatchKit Extension.appex". Is that the last part of the path for dlopen()?

Thanks!

Comment: You would only use `dlopen` if you're using a custom embedded framework. Not all extensions or watch apps do that. Are you? You didn't mention it.

Comment: Ah. I thought this technique applied to extensions as well for apps that need to run on earlier versions of iOS. Thanks for the clarification.